# Can a user belong to multiple organizations in github?

Tags: python, github

I was wondering if a user can belong to multiple organizations in GitHub. In their API, you can get an iterator or organizations, which leads me to believe that you can. If that is true, I'm not sure how to tell which organization object I get when I iteration over them (in python by the way).  Also, I'm using github3.py module.

So to recap, I'm wondering if a user can be in multiple organizations, and if yes, how can I tell which organization when iterating over the list.

Comment: This is the wrong forum for this question. The answer is, however, yes.